# AppCenter doesn't show updates or install anything

Tags: release-loki, updates, software-installation, appcenter

I have Loki installed on my laptop and desktop. Appcenter works fine on my laptop, but it doesn't on my desktop. It doesn't show any updates, that tab is empty. I can browse and search for software, but everything has an "install" button, even programs that are already installed. Pressing install results in either Appcenter freezing, or displaying "waiting" forever.

I can install, remove, and update things just fine from the terminal. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling appcenter, updating apt, and everything else I  could find here on Stack Exchange.
[image: Empty update tab]
Here's the empty update tab, no updates or current software is displayed.
[image: Files is not installed, according to Appcenter]
According to Appcenter, Pantheon-files is not installed (it is)

Comment: The same problem. Noticed it after last system update. I have tried to do ations from the comment above but no result. AppCenter works only when I reboot sysytem and choose the previous version https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc2if.png

Answer (score 1):

The elementary team has issued instructions on how to fix this (see https://medium.com/elementaryos/important-update-released-501c9d9f28b). Apparently there was a mismatch between AppCenter and packagekit.

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install packagekit`

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and this helped:

1.) remove the eOS repo:

`sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:elementary-os/daily`

2.) update/upgrade repos

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

3.) reboot

4.) add the repo back

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily`

5.) update/upgrade repos

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

this should upgrade the AppCenter app as well and it should work.

If not, try rebooting - it might help. For me the AppCenter sometimes works, sometimes doesn't... I just reboot and it's probably fine after the next boot.

Comment: This is quite a scary move to make: "Do NOT install this PPA if you want a tested running system, this PPA contains the newest and most unstable development of elementary, it's useful only if you are a developer and are not afraid to encounter CRITICAL BUGS.
Also this PPA may overwrite already installed packages you don't want it to!"